# Set the Pagination for SharePoint Get Items to be more than 100,000 inside our Power Automate flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow, power-platform

I have a service account with the following licenses:

[image: johnjohn123_0-1680041129241.png]

and we define a scheduled workflow that run on out list items each day at 12:00 am. the scheduled workflow has an action to get sharepoint items, and we can define maximum of 100,000 items as follow:

[image: johnjohn123_1-1680041220931.png]

then we need to Apply to each for the returned items. now in our case the items that we need to iterate over are around 150,000 items out of 2 million items inside the list.

So how we can get them all (the 150,000 items)? can we upgrade the service account license for example? or there are other approaches we can follow?

Comment: Does below answer help you in any way? Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Comment: Does below answer help you in any way? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) & [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible using Power automate flow to get more than 100,000 items using single Get items action.

100,000 items is the most you can get with **High** performance profile.

Here's is recommendation by Microsoft about overcoming this limit:

[image]

You can read more about limitations in Microsoft official documentation at: [Limits for automated, scheduled, and instant flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/limits-and-config)

Comment: I agree with Ganesh Sanap. I also don't think it's possible to fetch more than 100,000 items with a single "Get Items" action using a Power Automate process. Thank you for your support and understanding.